# Can I programmatically check what style a UITableViewCell is?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

While calculating a UITableViewCell's height, it'd be useful if I could tell what [style](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html) my UITableViewCell is set to. I don't see any properties on the cell itself. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, Apple does not expose the style property for UITableViewCell. But you have a couple options.

1. Create your own subclass of `UITableViewCell` that saves the style to a property when initWithStyle is called.

   ```
   @property UITableViewCellStyle cellStyle;

   // ...

   - (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
       self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
       if (self) {
           self.cellStyle = style;
       }
       return self;
   }
   ```
2. Save the style manually to the cell tag. You can then check the tag on the cell when you're setting the cell height. For example:

   ```
   UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:nil];
   cell.tag = UITableViewCellStyleValue1;
   ```

Comment: +1.  The first option is what I would do.  Subclassing not only allows you to save and access the information in the question, it makes it super-easy to save and access anything else you would need to associate with each cell.

Answer (score 2):

For some strange reason Apple didn't include a property in their public header however you can simply call valueForKey to get it:

```
UITableViewCellStyle style = [tableCell valueForKey:@"tableViewStyle"];
```

If using valueForKey concerns you, and you are using storyboards instead you could subclass and override:

```
- (nullable instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        _cellStyle = [aDecoder decodeIntForKey:@"UITableViewCellStyle"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

The other answers show how to get it for programatically created cells.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You can access the `style` method on your tableview to return the current style. [Here is a link to apple's documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/style)

**Edit:**

Whoops I just noticed you were asking about a UITableViewCell. Ideally you shouldn't need to know the style of the cell because you can't actually change the style of an existing cell. You can only initialize a cell with a style like this:

```
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:Cellidentifier];
```

Comment: Chase, I'm looking for the cell's style, not the table's. I'll add more information to my question to make this more clear.

Comment: Hmm. That's what I was afraid of but what if I want to implement heightForRowAtIndexPath and I want to do something different based on the cell type?

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, or at least not 100% reliably...

When you do `[cell initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:foo]` the chosen style is simply used to (re)layout the contents of the cell, specifically the layout of textLabel vs detailTextLabel. Thereafter the style no longer really matters... But what you *can* do is subsequently look at the resulting layout - namely the textLabel vs detailTextLabel frames - and deduce from their position & size what the original chosen style probably was [I say 'probably' because if the textLabel or detailTextLabel are nil there's really no way to, say, distinguish a UITableViewCellStyleDefault from UITableViewCellStyleValue1 from UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle, because you just have a textLabel and they all look the same].

That said, something like this may suffice for your needs (after `[cell layoutSubviews]` that is):

```
if (!CGRectGetHeight(cell.detailTextLabel.frame) {
    // UITableViewCellStyleDefault, b/c it never shows a detailTextLabel
} elseif (CGRectGetMinY(cell.detailTextLabel.frame) == CGRectGetMinY(cell.textLabel.frame)) {
    // UITableViewCellStyleValue1 or UITableViewCellStyleValue2
} else {
    // UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
}
```

Again, YMMV... this assumes your textLabel and detailTextLabel are *both* non-nil.

BTW You could further distinguish a UITableViewCellStyleValue1 from UITableViewCellStyleValue2 by looking at the labels' textAlignment, but there's really no way of knowing that these weren't re-aligned programmatically sometime after the cell was initWithStyle'd.

Having said all that, if you want to 100% reliably check after-the-fact what style your UITableViewCell was init'd to, then your safest bet is to make a simple subclass which overrides `-initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` and saves this in a new property; ie option 1 of accepted answer.